# Error while connecting "wallet connect" to vanilla js

Tags: web3js, walletconnect, qrcode

I am trying to integrate "wallet connect" to my simple vanilla js application but when the application runs, I get wallet connect option without QR code, its blank as shown below.

[image: wallet connect]

Also, in desktop options I don't see the "Metamask" option, please check below:
[image: no metamask option]

Below is my code:

index.html:

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web3/3.0.0-rc.5/web3.min.js">

</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@walletconnect/web3-provider@1.7.1/dist/umd/index.min.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
//An infura ID, or custom ETH node is required for Ethereum, for Binance Smart Chain you can just use their public endpoint
var provider = new WalletConnectProvider.default(
   { 
     infuraId: "891bf9c02f174bfb972b441073182320",
     //rpc: {56: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/"}
   });
 //to set it to BSC, uncomment the following line
 //provider.chainId = 56;

 //present the Wallet Connect QR code
 provider.enable().then(function(res){ 
   //get wallet addrs and then wrap this into the Web3 JS
   let web3 = new Web3(provider);
   //now do all the web3 stuff you want...
   //awesome web3 application goes here
 });
```